# Return a Message with HTTP Error Response Code in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

**How can a message body be added to a 404 response in flask?**

The following attempts will generate a 404 but without the message:

```
@app.route('/fruit/<fruit_name>', methods=["GET"])
def fruit_route(fruit_name):
    if fruit_name == "tomato":
        return "I don't care what they say, tomato is not a fruit", 404

    return "yummy"

@app.route('/fruit/<fruit_name>', methods=["GET"])
def fruit_route(fruit_name):
    if fruit_name == "tomato":
        flask.abort(404,"I don't care what they say, tomato is not a fruit")

    return "yummy"
```

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the builtin 404 error handler:

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return "I don't care what they say, tomato is not a fruit"

@app.route('/fruit/<fruit_name>', methods=["GET"])
def fruit_route(fruit_name):
  if fruit_name == "tomato":
     return flask.redirect('/404')
```

Answer (score 2):

Hellow !

I saw that you have already mentioned this issue as resolved. any way...

- you can add a description parameter in flask.abord()
  so it make sens to:
  falsk.abord(404, description="Lorem ipsum dolor...")

```
    @app.errorhandler(404)
    def page_not_found(e):
        return "{}, {}".format(e.message, e.description)
```